# d3.js: mix projected and unprojected geodata

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I made a map out of a custom geojson-file made with qgis. It has projected geodata instead of lat-long-values but didn't fit into the svg container automatically. So I moved it to the right place with the transform attribute. Here's my code so far:

```
var height = 800,
    width = 800;

var svg = d3.select("#map-container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);

d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json,"./data/Shapefiles_simplyfied_20.json")
    .await(drawMap);

function drawMap(error,bw) {

    if (error) throw error;

    var features = bw.features;

    var map = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "kommunen")
        .attr("id","karte-rdb");

    map
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.geoPath(null))
        .attr("transform","scale(1,-1)")

    //make the map fit to svg container
    var bbox = d3.select("#karte-rdb")._groups[0][0].getBBox();
    var scaleFactor = d3.min([width / bbox.width, height / bbox.height]);
    var translation = [width - bbox.x,height - bbox.y];

    map
        .attr("transform","scale("+scaleFactor+","+scaleFactor+") translate("+ translation[0] +","+ translation[1] +")")

}
```

The (truncated) geojson looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Shapefiles",
"crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
},
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "GEN": "Area1",
        "BEZ": "RDB-RP"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [[[[393361.666451968252659,
        5504072.610383642837405],
        [393366.833893342292868,
        5503968.659385782666504],
        ...
```

[image]

Now I would like to display some points that are in a csv file with lat-lon-pairs.

```
Name    lat lon
A   7.601581    49.203633
B   8.008745    50.374521
C   8.11676     49.746425
D   6.657145    50.221658
E   6.942947    49.654687
F   9.62743     51.196755
```

How can I display them together with the projected geodata without a d3.geoProject-function?

Comment: If you have lat/lon points and are displaying the map using the right projection, everything should be fine. The problem is when you don't know which projection the data is using, or when you are using the wrong projection: sometimes it will seems to work if you scale/translate but it is really not. If your lat/lon points are not in the right location then you are probably displaying using a projection that does not match the data. There is no such a thing as "unprojected" data in a flat map: earth is (almost) spherical, you can't turn spherical into flat without a projection algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, not easily, there are alternatives.

The projected data you are using is projected onto a grid of meters or yards or whatever. To project latitude longitude points onto that grid, you need to translate your latitude longitude points to that grid using a projection (you also need depending on map scale, the same datum, but let's assume all your geographic data uses the same datum). The formula to project your points will be dependent on the projection you are using for your already projected layer. This is more complex than the alternatives:

1. As most projections in QGIS can be converted fairly easily, you could convert your latitude longitude coordinates (if placed in geojson or other geographical format) into projected points that share the same projection as your data.
2. The other option would be to "unproject" your already projected data so that it comprises lat long pairs (generally you would use the datum WGS84 if using d3), and then project all your data with d3. You indicated that you didn't want to use a d3.projection, however, so this might not be ideal.

Either of these options would play well with d3. Conversely, combining a geoProjection with a geoTransform or a null projection, will lead to a lot of headache when rescaling, zooming, etc. Also, you can use a `.geoTransform` with your projected data, which *may* offer some advantages as compared with scaling and translating the svg directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using d3.projection is also possible but I was not able to convert die x-y-coordinates to lat-lon-values in qgis, which I need for correct projections. But the answer here gave me the right hint to solve this problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250720/creating-geojson-with-lat-lon-out-of-shapefile-using-qgis